# Is there a setting that makes all windows pop up in a specific display in XFCE?

Tags: multiple-monitors, xfce

I'm currently using dual monitors in XFCE.  I have the position of the screens set up just fine, but when I open new applications, they always show up on the screen that's on the left.  (Which is my laptop's screen.)

I would like to choose a primary monitor for new applications to open on.  Is this possible?

Intel GPU, with OS drivers

Comment: Does your right monitor shows up as a primary monitor in `xrandr -q`?